# How to create a Dataframe/ Table in netlogo?

Tags: netlogo

I am wondering whether is it possible to make a table in netlogo where the left most/first column represents the agent-x who number (i.e agent-x 1, agent-x 2 ...) and the top/first row represents agent-y 's who number (i.e agent-y 23,agent-y 37).

The distances between the agents will be added to the corresponding cells. The result will be something similar to Excel, where if column B, contains agent-x 1 and row B contains agent-y 23 the corresponding cell for column B and row B will contain the distance between the two agents (i.e 8 units).

Comment: You can, using an Output widget on the interface, and constructing the text to send to the output area with `word` and placing it on the output area with commands like `output-type`. So your users could read it, but it couldn't be used for analysis. You can export data for analysis. Perhaps some more information about what you want this for would stimulate an answer.